# Converting ms to hours, min, secs giving empty result

Tags: java

I want to convert a long of ms to days, hours, minutes, and seconds but sometimes the result is empty and just "".

My method is,

```
public static String getTime(long enlapsed) {
long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(enlapsed);
enlapsed -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);

long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(enlapsed);
enlapsed -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);

long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(enlapsed);
enlapsed -= TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);

long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(enlapsed);

String result = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
return result.replace("0d ", "").replace("0h ", "").replace("0m ", "").replace("0s ", ""); 
}
```

I can't figure out why the result would be empty.

Comment: On which given `time` the result is empty? Also, can you try to print the `result` before replacing and returning the result?

Comment: can you example a wrong Time?

Comment: Your code is working properly when entered the correct `enlapsed`. Can you show us the value of `enlapsed` that results to ""?

Comment: As per my answer, elapsed times under 1000 milliseconds will yield empty results.

Comment: FYI: [`java.time.Duration.ofMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#ofMillis(long))

Answer (score 4):

Due to the `replace()` calls in your return statement, every time the **elapsed time is under one second**, the result will be an empty string.

```
return result.replace("0d ", "").replace("0h ", "").replace("0m ", "").replace("0s ", "");
```

With an input of `0d 0h 0m 0s`, the result will be empty as everything will be replaced.